# How to edit my business on Google My Business?

Tags: google-my-business

The old business is closed. The address is the same, but the Name and Type of business have changed. How can I edit this in?

```
Jocelyn Ross
Officiant on Demand (New Business Name)
...@gmail.com
630.640.4244
```

Answer (score 1):

> - Sign in to **[Google My Business](http://business.google.com/?gmbsrc=ww-ww-et-gs-z-gmb-v-z-h~bhc-core-u)**.
> - If you have multiple locations, open the location you'd like to manage.
> - Click **Info** from the menu.
> - Click the section that you want to change, then enter the new information in the box that appears. To remove a section, next to the
>     section, click Remove **×**. Keep in mind:
>
>   - Removing information
>       you’ve previously added could take up to 60 days.
>   - You cannot
>       remove information that’s also publicly available or from other
>       sources.
>   - You cannot edit **[editorial summaries](https://support.google.com/business/answer/6088158)** or keywords from the
>       web that appear next to your business.
> - Click **Apply**.
>
> **[https://support.google.com/business/answer/3039617](https://support.google.com/business/answer/3039617?hl=en)**